# Can I use JavaScript in an extension to quit chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to figure out a way to actually quit Google Chrome using JavaScript, it's for an extension i'm building.

All I could find is a way to use Chrome's API to close Chrome's windows/tabs.

Comment: doubt it... Not really sure myself, but it seems like a security risk that they wouldn't let you do?

Comment: I am pretty sure allowing JavaScript to quit the browser would be a security issue, and 100% sure that would annoy the hell out of web users.

Comment: Well, the security risk of installing an extension is probably a lot bigger than the relatively low-risk denial of service that closing Chrome presents. I agree with JavaScript in general, but extensions *already* can do a lot more than mere web sites.

Comment: Nimrod: would closing all tabs/windows be good enough? Or do you need to stop the actual Chrome process(es)?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, using the `remove()` function when you have the `windows` permission, in the format:

```
chrome.windows.remove(windowId, callback)
```

Check out the [API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) for more details.

Comment: And if it is a tab: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove

Comment: Hi Tom Walters, I am using that function right now, though I'm don't use the permission. Still works though..

Comment: @NimrodSarda Doing it without permission eh? You crazy guy! There's no method to directly close Chrome, it would still be running. If you want a more reliable way of timing an application to close I'd suggest writing a (bash/etc.) separate script for users to download.